Looker Studio Connection Issue with Snowflake Data Source
I am facing an issue while connecting the Snowflake data source to Looker Studio. The dashboard loads the data correctly during the initial setup, but it breaks on every refresh. During these times, we have to manually edit the dashboard and reload the data.
Here are the error details:
Data Set Configuration Error
Looker Studio cannot connect to your data set.
Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set
Error ID: 4ddeb776

Can you please investigate this issue and provide a solution to ensure the dashboard remains stable and refreshes correctly?

Ok - but as you haven’t provided any information about your connection, its settings, whether you can see the connection attempt in Snowflake, etc, it’s very difficult for anyone to help you.

I noticed this issue occurring when I use a pivot table in Looker Studio with a Snowflake dataset, but the dashboard is not broken when using a common table.
